# Java Game freezing on mouse click

Tags: java, swing, freeze, mouselistener

I working on a small project and came across something that I didn't know how to fix. I tried looking into threads to see if this was the problem, but couldn't find anything to help me. The problem is that whenever I click on the frame, the key input, animations, etc, all freeze.

Here's the code for the main class: (let me know if you need code from any of the other classes, but I think the problem lies here)

```
package me.runeglaive.main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import me.runeglaive.gamestate.GameStateManager;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static int height = 360;
    public static int width = height * 16 / 9;
    public static int scale = 2;

    private JFrame frame;
    private Graphics g;

    private boolean running = true;

    GameStateManager gsm;

    public Game(){
        frame = new JFrame("Game");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setSize(width * scale, height * scale);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        gsm = new GameStateManager();

        init();

        MouseListener ml = new MouseListener(){

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                gsm.mousePressed(e);
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                gsm.mouseReleased(e);
            }

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
        };

        KeyListener kl = new KeyListener(){

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
                gsm.keyPressed(k);
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {
                gsm.keyReleased(k);
            }

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k) {

            }

        };
        frame.addKeyListener(kl);
        frame.addMouseListener(ml);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void init(){

    }

    public void update(double delta){
        gsm.update(delta);
    }

    public void render(){

        //double buffering
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null){
            createBufferStrategy(2);
            return;
        }

        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        //clear screen
        g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        //Draw gameState
        gsm.render(g);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public synchronized void start(){
        running = true;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        running = false;
    }

    public void run() {

            //initialize time loop variables
            long lastLoopTime = System.nanoTime();
            final int TARGET_FPS = 60;
            final long OPTIMAL_TIME = 1000000000 / TARGET_FPS;
            double lastFpsTime = 0;

            while(running)
            {
                //Calculate since last update
                long now = System.nanoTime();
                long updateLength = now - lastLoopTime;
                lastLoopTime = now;
                double delta = updateLength / ((double)OPTIMAL_TIME);

                //update frame counter
                lastFpsTime += updateLength;

                //update FPS counter
                if(lastFpsTime >= 1000000000)
                {
                    lastFpsTime = 0;
                }

                //game updates
                update(delta);

                //graphics (gameState)
                render();

                try{
                    Thread.sleep((Math.abs(lastLoopTime - System.nanoTime() + OPTIMAL_TIME)/1000000));
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    System.out.println("Error in sleep");
                }
            }
        }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Game().start();
    }
}
```

Heres the Game State Manager:

```
package me.runeglaive.gamestate;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GameStateManager {

    private ArrayList<GameState> states;

    private int currentState;

    public static final int MENUSTATE = 0;
    public static final int MAINSTATE = 1;

    public GameStateManager(){
        states = new ArrayList<GameState>();
        states.add(new MenuState(this));
        states.add(new MainState(this));

        setState(MAINSTATE);
    }

    public void setState(int state){
        currentState = state;
        states.get(state).init();
    }

    public int getCurrentState(){
        return currentState;
    }

    public void update(double delta){
        states.get(currentState).update(delta);
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        states.get(currentState).render(g);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k){
        states.get(currentState).keyPressed(k);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k){
        states.get(currentState).keyReleased(k);
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        states.get(currentState).mousePressed(e);
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
        states.get(currentState).mouseReleased(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code for `GameStateManager`.

Comment: I think you should extend `JPanel` or `JFrame` and use `paintComponent` instead of `render`

Comment: Well, we have to see `MenuState` and `MainState` too. But undoubtedly one of them performs some long running task on the Event Dispatch Thread. Swing/AWT is single-threaded so all event callbacks must return or the interface freezes.

Comment: @Frakcool As far as I can tell, no, there not.

Answer (score 0):

What is the code for gsm.mousePressed(e); and gsm.mouseReleased(e) please? :)

You're misusing Java Swing. You shall not create an own thread and redraw the scene programmatically, since this interferes with the threading model of the input queue.

If you're using swing, then instead of starting an own thread, start up a swing timer. Call the update from the event listener of the timer. Instead of calling render, issue a repaint() on the frame and override the painting code of the frame if you want to play nice.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html

In case of AWT, there is both system triggered painting and application triggered paiting.

The code you're doing is a perfectly valid brute force game coder thinking - and perfectly valid if you're having a full control on the screen. In case of Swing, this is not the case, as Swing does take care of a lot more. If you're messing with Mr.Swing, it will bite you sooner or later ;-)

If you prefer taking this game development more seriously, look for a Java 2D game engine, or a Java 3D game engine (such as jMonkey) which takes care of all the details and offer working vertical retrace sync - which is unavoidable for smooth movements. Note that your BufferStrategy will *not* take care of that, this topic is a way more complex.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, I changed render to the paint method, bit it still doesn't work. Should I just make a swing timer do the game updates, and stop creating a thread?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I am saying :) You may also show the code called when you click a button.

Comment: I think you need to have a look at [`BufferStrategy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) and [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) to understand what the OP is actually doing, what they've done isn't a misuse of the Swing API

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I understand your point. I am not 100% sure if it is a threading misuse or not, I'd need to see what is happening in those gsm methods such as gsm.render(g); for real. From my previous experiences, I'd say it is very likely something fishy happens if you use a thread to do swing things. I have studied bufferedStrategy deeply earlier, and have my own GUI engine built on that, which works well in production.